# Ida pro gragh output batch mode

Tags: ida, gdlib, disassembly

Can anyone let me know how we are going to output all the subroutine's graphs in batch mode suing `IDC`. i.e. I have 447 subroutine's and wanna be output them all and I would like to make sure I first retrieve all the routines address automatically, cuz by knowing the address I can simply use `GenFuncCall`.
P.S: Is this the only cfg that I can get from Ida Pro given a binary dis-assembled file?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is about: do you want to generate a GDL file for each of your routines, all XREF between routines, XREFs from/to of all BBLs inside your routines? Could you clarify what's your intent?

Comment: Yes, I can generate .dot (gdl) files for my routines based on the address and/OR all of them once specifying the start/end address of all. But what if we don't know the address of all routines? Couldn't find a method to retrieve the routines address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the address of all known functions in the IDB, you could use something like this using IDAPython (just an example):

```
def main():
    for count, func_ea in enumerate(Functions()):
        if func_ea == BADADDR:
            break
        func_name = GetFunctionName(funcea)
        func_start = func_ea

        print("[{:4}] name: {}; start address: {:#x}".format(count, func_name, func_start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed a CFG of my whole program,the base example I started from was:
 https://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/examples/ex_gdl_qflow_chart.py

It uses the flow chart class: 
 https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idaapi.FlowChart-class.html

also worth noting to trigger in batch mode, you'll want something like this

> idal64 -A -S{yourscriptname}.py {yourbinary}

Tips:

- Prototype the script in the IDAPro gui first
- Opening of the graph processor can cause timing issues, its hacky, but something like delaying execution of the script seemed to help, e.g.

  `idaapi.autoWait()
  Timer(2, idacfg).start()`

  where idacfg is your python function from the example
- print to stdout doesn't seem to work in batch mode, so you'll want to set stdout to a file for your debugging.
- Closing the GUI in batch mode is still an issue for me.

Hope that helps.